# Structured streaming schema from Kafka JSON - query error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark 3.2 for getting JSONs streaming from Kafka 2.12-3.0.0.
I'm receiving error in query after parsing JSONs.

**Kafka topic streaming JSONs:**

```
b'{"pmu_id": 2, "time": 1642771653.06, "stream_id": 2,"analog": [], "digital": 0, "frequency": 49.99, "rocof": 1}'
b'{"pmu_id": 2, "time": 1642734653.06, "stream_id": 2,"analog": [], "digital": 0, "frequency": 50.00, "rocof": -1}'
```

**DataFrame schema:**

```
stream01Schema= StructType()\
    .add("pmu_id", ByteType())\
    .add("time", TimestampType()).add("stream_id", ByteType())
    .add("analog", StringType()).add("digital", ByteType()).add("frequency", FloatType()).add("rocof", ByteType())
```

**Constructing a streaming DataFrame that reads from topic:**

```
stream01DF = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
        .option("subscribe", kafka_topic_name) \
        .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
        .load()
        .select(col("key").cast("string") from_json(col("value").cast("string").alias("pmudata"), stream01Schema))
```

**Printing resulting schema:**

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- from_json(CAST(value AS STRING) AS pmudata): struct (nullable = true)    
 |    |-- pmu_id: byte (nullable = true)
 |    |-- time: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- stream_id: byte (nullable = true)
 |    |-- analog: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- digital: byte (nullable = true)
 |    |-- frequency: float (nullable = true)
 |    |-- rocof: byte (nullable = true)
```

**Testing query:**

```
testQuery = stream01DF.groupBy("pmudata.rocof").count()    
testQuery.writeStream \
  .outputMode("complete") \
  .format("console") \
  .option("truncate", False) \
  .start() \
  .awaitTermination()
```

**Error received:**

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'pmudata.rocof' given input columns: [from_json(CAST(value AS STRING) AS pmudata), key];
```

Comment: The `AS pmudata` didn't properly alias the column. Please show where you set `pmu214DF`

Comment: I've corrected that and updated answer with all relevant info.

Comment: As mentioned in the other question, did you try `from_json(col("value").cast("string"), stream01Schema).alias("pmudata")`? In other words, you want to parse the json using a schema **then** alias that. That's the same usage that's in the blog I linked to

Comment: Finally it worked! Thank you! Please put it in answer so I can accept it. I'll delete my previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're looking for this since you are trying to alias the `from_json()` column (check your parentheses) to a name, which you can later select/group by.

`from_json(col("value").cast("string"), stream01Schema).alias("pmudata")`

A complete usage is in the end-to-end example in [this Databricks post](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html)